# Gap on left side of nav bar displacing entire nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement this nav bar into my site, but the nav bar is being displaced by a gap that I am unable to remove. How to I remove this negative space?

Cheers

Source Code: http://www.marcofolio.net/css/the_apple.com_navigation_menu_created_using_only_css3.html

Cheer.

HTML

```
    <nav>            
             <ul id="appleNav">
                 <li><a href="#" title="logo"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Camera Logos" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
                <li><a href="pinhole.html" title="Pinhole Camera">Pinhole Camera</a></li>
                <li><a href="photogram.html" title="The Photogram">The Photogram</a></li>
                <li><a href="film.html" title="Film">Film</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
/* APPLE STYLE NAVIGATION MENU */
    #appleNav {
        margin:40px 0; list-style:none;
        left: 660px;

    /* Lucinda Grande is the font used on the website from Apple. */
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:-0.5px; font-size:13px;

    /* Apply a subtle text-shadow to the text */
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;

    /* We want to add the shadow to the complete navigation menu. In order to do that, we'll need to set
    the correct width and height, and also the correct borders, in order to create the perfect drop shadow */
        width:732px; height:34px;

        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
         border-radius:4px;

        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b;
}

#appleNav li {
    display:block; float:left; border-right:1px solid #5d5d5d; border-left:1px solid #929292; width:200px; height:34px; border-bottom:1px solid #575757; border-top:1px solid #797979;

    /* Gradient backgrounds for the buttons. Generated using http://gradients.glrzad.com/ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #787878), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #787878 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%);
    background-color:#5f5f5f; /* Fallback */
}

/* Set the states when hovering, except for the last item in the list (the search bar), since it doesn't need to change */
#appleNav li:not(:last-child):hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
    background-color:#383838; /* Fallback */

    /* We use the inset of the box shadow to create a subtle inner glow when hovering */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
}

/* When the user clicks the button, we simply change the box inset (compared to the "hover") */
#appleNav li:not(:last-child):active {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
    background-color:#383838; /* Fallback */

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
}

#appleNav li a {
    color:white; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; display:block; line-height:34px; outline:none; }



    /* We use the CSS3 multiple backgrounds for the input field: The magnifier image and the gradient background */    
    background-image: url("../images/magnifier.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #747474), color-stop(0.5, #6E6E6E), color-stop(0.51, #7E7E7E), color-stop(1, #8D8D8D));
    background-image: url("../images/magnifier.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #747474 0%, #6E6E6E 50%, #7E7E7E 51%, #8D8D8D 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-color:#6E6E6E; /* Fallback */

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
}

/* Rounded corner for the first in last item. Shorthand: Top left, Top right, Bottom right, Bottom left.
We also remove the borders, since they don't need them. */
#appleNav li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    border-left:none;
}

/* The first child image - the logo - has to be centered. Because of the image dimensions, we manually need to shift it a bit. */
#appleNav li:first-child a img {
   vertical-align:middle; margin-top:-2px;
}

#appleNav li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;

    border-right:none;

    /* The width of the last menu item (search bar) is bigger than the others */
    width:124px;
}

/* Fade in animation (Webkit only) */
@-webkit-keyframes showMenu {
    from { opacity: 0; top:-20px; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#appleNav {
     -webkit-animation: showMenu 1s; position:relative;
}
```

Comment: where is the space in this link http://demo.marcofolio.net/apple_menu/?

Comment: Add `padding: 0` to `#appleNav`. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/dzwhsk75/

Comment: try to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding: 0` to `#appleNav` to remove that "white" space, or random gap to the left.

A fiddle for demonstration:

With `padding: 0px`

http://jsfiddle.net/dzwhsk75/3/

[image]

Without

http://jsfiddle.net/dzwhsk75/4/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a random gap. Unordered lists have default browser styles, including padding and margin, applied to them and if you don't remove them then that's what you get.